# Ramified Geometric Langlands

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, geometric-langlands

Is the following a reasonable formulation of (a part of) the geometric Langlands conjecture for $\mathrm{GL}_n$ over a curve $X$?

(*) Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an irreducible rank $n$ $\ell$-adic local system (=lisse sheaf) on $X-S$, where $S$ is a finite set of points. Then there exists a Hecke eigensheaf on the moduli stack $\mathrm{Bun}_n$, of rank $n$ vector bundles on $X$ equipped with appropriate level structures on $S$, whose Hecke eigenvalue is $\mathcal{L}$.

For $n=1$, this amounts to the global class field theory, so I will restrict to the case $n>1$. 
If $S$ is empty then this statement was proved for $n=2$ by Drinfeld and for arbitrary $n$ by Frenkel--Gaitsgory--Vilonen. If $S$ is non-empty (i.e. $\mathcal{L}$ is ramified) then much less is known. For instance, I know of only one case when this statement has been established in presence of wild singularities. This is when $X=\mathbb{P}^1$ and $\mathcal{L}$ is the generalised Kloosterman sheaf (which has wild singularity at $\infty$ and tame singularity at $0$). The above statement in this case was proved by Heinloth--Ngo--Yun.

I appreciate it if somebody can point out a reference where the conjecture is precisely formulated and also if people can list all the known cases.

------------------------ Added in edit:

Here are bolder assertion:

**) The same statement is expected to hold if we consider all local systems (not just irreducible ones).

***) There is a bijection between local systems on open dense subsets of $X$ and (equivalence classes of) Hecke eigensheaves on $\mathrm{Bun}_n$ (equipped with appropriate level structure at the ramified points).

-------------------- Added in further edit: 
As David Ben-Zvi points out, ** and *** are not precise enough as they don't take into account Arthur's parameters. How about the following statement:

*+) There is a canonical bijection between **irreducible** rank $n$ local systems on open dense subsets of $X$ and (equivalence classes of) **cuspidal** Hecke eigensheaves on $\mathrm{Bun}_n$ (equipped with appropriate level structure at the ramified points).

At the decategorified level, this would give the classical (i.e. non-geometric)  bijection between irreducible Galois representations and cuspidal automorphic representations, proved by Drinfeld and L. Lafforgue.

Of course, to make any of this precise one has to specify what one means by a Hecke eigensheaf in the ramified situation. One place this is (roughly) discussed is in the introduction of Heinloth's [PhD thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0302210). Another place is in Section 4.3 of Yun's [CDM paper](http://math.mit.edu/~zyun/CDM_published.pdf), though the latter also includes an "automorphic data" in the definition (which we may or may not want).

------------More precise formulation:

As Will and David point out, one needs to specify what one really means by Hecke eigensheaf and by level structures before one can judge if *+ is reasonable. It is not clear to me how to handle this. But here is an attempt.

Let $K$ be a compact open subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})$. Then, I believe, we do know what a Hecke eigensheaf on 
$\mathrm{GL}_n(k(X))\backslash \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})/K$ is. Let us call this a $K$-Hecke eigensheaf. Let us call a $K$-Hecke eigensheaf $E$ and $K'$-Hecke eigensheaf $E'$ *equivalent* if there exist a subgroup $K''\subset K\cap K'$ such that the pullbacks of $E$ and $E'$ to 
$\mathrm{GL}_n(k(X))\backslash \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})/{K''}$
are isomorphic.

Now I guess conjecture *+ is that there is a bijection between irreducible local systems and equivalence classes of Hecke eigensheaves.

Note that one could (and perhaps should) define the equivalence using Yun's notion of automorphic data. This means that in addition to $K$, we also a choose a character $\chi$ of $K$.

A further intriguing alternative (suggested by Will Sawin) is to use the conductor. That might remove the ambiguity of this $K$.

Comment: I think there are a few other examples, but not changing the basic point. (1) Either in HNY or in Yun's follow-up work, I believe one can handle the generalized Kloosterman sheaves of Katz (which have non-unipotent tame ramification at 0). (2) For GL_1 one can handle arbitrary wild ramification without much difficulty.

Comment: Thanks Will. I edited the question, taking your comments into account.

Comment: This statement should be true but should also be far from the strongest possible conjecture.

Comment: @dhy What do you think a stronger conjecture is (other than the obvious specifying which spaces the eigensheaves live on?) I thought there was difficulty formulating the correct statement in the ramified setting.

Comment: @WillSawin In the categorical geometric setting (so char 0 & with D-modules) the strongest statement should be (modulo issues of non-temperedness) that $\operatorname{D-mod}(\operatorname{Bun}(X-S))$ and $\operatorname{QCoh}(\operatorname{LocSys}(X-S))$ correspond to each other under local categorical geometric Langlands. Of course, to extract concrete statements from this you need to pin down exactly what local geometric Langlands is. E.g., the knowledge that $\text{D-mod(Affine grassmannian)}$ corresponds under LGL to $\text{QCoh(pt/}\hat{G})$ recovers the unramified statement, the knowledge

Comment: that $\text{D-mod(Affine flag variety)}$ corresponds to $\operatorname{QCoh}(\hat{b}/\hat{B})$ recovers the tame (w unipotent monodromy) statements. There are even some correspondences which get into arbitrary ramification, e.g. that $g((t))-\operatorname{mod}_{crit}$ should correspond to $\text{QCoh(Opers)}$, and from that you can extract (rather painful) arbitrary ramification statements. Admittedly the original question was in the $l$-adic sheaf setting, where I believe that roughly the same story should hold but I am scared to write down any concrete statements...

Comment: But at the end of the day, one should be able to write down for every $\mathcal{L}$ an "explicit" category $C$ (described e.g. as a certain category of Whittaker sheaves) with a map from $C$ to the category of $\mathcal{L}$-eigensheaves. (And maybe one can do even more... but at this point already I would need to assume multiple wide open conjectures to even formulate my statements. And I am having difficulty expressing what I want to say in the space of the comment box.)

Comment: @dhy Thanks for your comments! I don't think anyone has formulated a good purely $\ell$-adic notion of $\operatorname{QCoh}$ so maybe one should look to the Betti geometric Langlands correspondence, for which tame ramification is part of the original picture and presumably wild ramification can be added somehow.

Comment: Hi dhy, Thanks for the comments. I am for the moment interested only in the $\ell$-adic statement. Also, I'm after a precise statement prefarably in a reference. For instance, it is not clear to me if we need to restrict to "irreducible" local systems in (*). In addition, I would like to know what has actually been proven.

Comment: It seems to me that $(**)$ and $(***)$ are not precise. Just in the unramified case, assuming the GLC, the category of Hecke eigensheaves for say the trivial local system is not a copy of Vect like at an irreducible one, but looks like the fiber of IndCoh_N(Loc) at the trivial local system, which is roughly stratified by copies of Vect associated to nilpotent orbits. In other words, you really have copies of Vect labeled not by Langlands parameters (Loc) but by Arthur parameters..

Comment: As @dhy pointed out the correct ramified categorical statement ASSUMES the data of the local Langlands correspondence -- i.e., you don't get to make in general the statement "category A and category B are equivalent" but rather "A and B correspond via local Langlands". In the unramified and tame cases we know exactly what local Langlands does so can make statements about equivalences of categories -- but eg in the tame case the answer won't be in terms of sheaves on ramified Loc, but sheaves on Loc + data of flag -- ie you have to add structure to the stacks of local systems too.

Comment: @WillSawin In the Betti case something nice happens, in that the tame and wild stories totally decouple in a sense: the spaces of wild local systems MAP to those of tame ones, so once you prove a tame Betti statement you just can couple it to a purely local statement (suitable module categories for the affine Hecke category line up on the automorphic and spectral side) to get the general wild statement. Of course, like most things in the Betti story, this picture is clear on the spectral side and totally mysterious on the automorphic side...

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi If you work with nonstandard level structures, the niloptent cone is sometimes a pullback from the nilpotent cone of a moduli space with a smaller level structure - maybe in this setting it's easier to see the analogous structure on the automorphic side?

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi: Thanks for pointing out the sloppiness in the formulation of **) and ***). Please see the new statement *+).

Comment: @Dr.Evil  I'm likely being dense but it seems to me *+ is still off.. say I have an irreducible local system, which corresponds to an irreducible cuspidal automorphic rep unramified away from some points where say it corresponds to irreducible Iwahori-Hecke modules of dimension $>1$. Then the space of corresponding Hecke eigenfunctions (prescribing the action of the spherical Hecke algebras at all unramified points) is also of dimension bigger than one, right? so on the sheaf level also we'd expect a bunch of Hecke eigensheaves with eigenvalue the prescribed local system.

Comment: It just seems that focusing on the Hecke eigencondition is not enough to pin down sheaves either at reducible local systems or in the presence of noncommutative Hecke algebras.

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi Doesn't this all depend on what is meant by "appropriate level structure"? If we take an Iwahori level structure then as you say, there is no hope for a  bijection. But if we take a mirabolic level structure which matches the conductor of the representation then maybe there is hope.

Comment: @Dr.Evil Why do you think we may not want automorphic data? We need this data to specify what space our sheaves are sheaves on. The main question is  rather for which automorphic data the statement true, and for which we can prove it. My other comment, to David Ben-Zvi, maybe underscores this.

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi: As Will is suggesting, we need not necessarily take Iwahori. In fact, reading Heinloth's first paragraph, it appears for any local system, we can always take a compact open subgroup K for which there is a unique eigenfunction. So perhaps that is the correct level structure to take.

Comment: @WillSawin: The reason I said we might or might not want automorphic data is because I thought may be we want to work with Heinloth's formulation (see previous comment). Of course, a compact open is also a particular case of automorphic data, but this takes a lot less words to define than automorphic data in full generality.

Comment: Fair enough - though this is a very specifically $GL_n$ point of view, seems more natural to me to speak in terms of automorphic representations..